# awk script matching several fields in 2 files

Tags: awk

Could you please help to write an awk script for the following?
I've got two files where I need to compare two fields? for example:

**file1:**

```
asdf 1.1.1.1
qwert 2.2.2.2
kjldjf 3.3.3.3
jkhkdhsfk 4.4.4.4
```

**file2:**

```
asdf 1.1.1.5
qwert 2.2.2.5
kjldjf 3.3.3.3
jkhkdhsfk 4.4.4.4
```

I need to print all the entries where field 1 of file1 matches field 1 of file2 AND 
at the same time field 2 of file1 does not match field 2 of file2.
For example I need to get the following lines:

```
asdf 1.1.1.1 -> 1.1.1.5
qwert 2.2.2.2 -> 2.2.2.5
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat f1
asdf 1.1.1.1
qwert 2.2.2.2
kjldjf 3.3.3.3
jkhkdhsfk 4.4.4.4

$ cat f2
asdf 1.1.1.5
qwert 2.2.2.5
kjldjf 3.3.3.3
jkhkdhsfk 4.4.4.4
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a && $2!=a[$1]{print $1,a[$1],"->",$2}' f1 f2
asdf 1.1.1.1 -> 1.1.1.5
qwert 2.2.2.2 -> 2.2.2.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally I wouldn't answer to such a bold freebie order but I got curious and tried it anyway:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} a[$1]!=$2{print $1,a[$1],$2}' file1 file2
asdf 1.1.1.1  1.1.1.5
qwert 2.2.2.2  2.2.2.5
```

Comment: the only thing is that it keeps both fields the same but need to be different. I mean the purpose is to find entries different in the second field but same in the first one, that is asdf 1.1.1.1 -> 1.1.1.5

Comment: @gregarah Yeah sorry my bad: there was a typo in the latter `{action}` part, I fixed `$i` to `$1`...

Comment: @JamesBrown: Ha! `I wouldn't answer to such a bold freebie order`, that is so typical of you. `++`